# Select sibling before an element

Tags: jquery, siblings

The HTML content looks like this:

```
<div class="year">
    <div class="month">
        <div class="week">
            <div class="day">1</div>
            <div class="day">2</div>
            <div class="day">3</div>
            <div class="day">4</div>
            <div class="day">5</div>
            <div class="day">6</div>
            <div class="day">7</div>
        </div>
        ........
    </div>
    <div class="month">
        ............
    </div>
</div>
<div class="year">
    <div class="month">
        <div class="week">
            <div class="day">1</div>
            <div class="day">2</div>
            <div class="day">3</div>
            <div class="day">4</div>
            <div class="day">5</div>
            <div class="day">6</div>
            <div class="day">7</div>
        </div>
        ........
    </div>
    <div class="month">
        ............
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to select sibling `day`  of the selected one.For example If I mouse over and mouse out every `day` in every week or month or year, is there a way for me to access its siblings before that one and change the color?

Here is what I write but does not work correctly :

```
    $(".day").each(function(){
        $(this).mouseover(function(){
        $(this).prevAll().css("background", "red")
    })
    $(this).mouseout(function(){
        $(this).prevAll().css("background", " ");
    });
    })
```

Comment: using `prevAll` will apply background color to all previous `divs` .Instead use [prev()](https://api.jquery.com/prev/)

Comment: Use `addClass` / `removeClass` rather than `css("background..` - you'll have more control.

Comment: Re @Swati comment - Raha, your title says "sibling before" but your question says "its sibling**s**" - which do you want?

Comment: @freedomn-m sorry for my wrong explanation, I want to access to sibling before of an day element which is  mouse over / out ,  all previous days before day selected .

Comment: It looks work just for sibling before for a week , not all week and month and year  befor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should do the job. But in general it is a better idea to use `.add/removeClass()` to change the formatting of your divs.

In my snippet I used a delegated eventlistening (`.on(...)`). This is more lightweight as it affects fewer elements and will also work for dynamically added elements. There is no need to use the `each()` method as jQuery will apply  its actions automatically to all selected elements.

```js
$('.week').on('mouseover mouseout','.day',function(ev){
   let days=$(".day");
   days.css("background-color","");     
   ev.type=="mouseover" &&  days.slice(0,days.index(this)).css("background-color","red");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
 
<div class="year">
<div class="month">
    <div class="week">
        <div class="day">1</div>
        <div class="day">2</div>
        <div class="day">3</div>
        <div class="day">4</div>
        <div class="day">5</div>
        <div class="day">6</div>
        <div class="day">7</div>
    </div>
    ........
</div>
<div class="month">
    ............
</div>
</div>
<div class="year">
<div class="month">
    <div class="week">
        <div class="day">1</div>
        <div class="day">2</div>
        <div class="day">3</div>
        <div class="day">4</div>
        <div class="day">5</div>
        <div class="day">6</div>
        <div class="day">7</div>
    </div>
    ........
</div>
<div class="month">
    ............
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @cars10m for your answer,for example but if I mouse over a day in second week of second month all previous days should be colored not only the days at the second week of second month